# Add data-design attribute to canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Hey Stack**overflow** community,

I'm trying to add a swf image to a canvas element using Js.

The HTML which contains the canvas element does look like the following:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div id="builder" style="background: #FFF url('assets/images/canvas.png') repeat;" class="thumb" data-design="<?php echo 'http://assets.zwinky.com/assets3/avatar/avatar10.8.swf?u=' . $user->username; ?>">
        <canvas style="position: relative; display: block; width: 100%;" width="565" height="656"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Been testing JS/Jquery as the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var design = $("#builder").attr('data-design');
        var canvas = $("#builder").find('canvas')[0];
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        };
        img.src = design;
    });
</script>
```

How could I add the `data-design` attribute which contains the swf url to the canvas element?

Hope someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var design = $("#builder").attr('data-design');
        var canvas = $("#builder").find('canvas')[0];
        canvas.setAttribute('data-design',design);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        };
        img.src = design;
    });
</script>
```